# MemoryError while training large dataset using naive bayes classifier

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, machine-learning, nltk

I am trying to train naive bayes classifier using set of keywords for different categories.

Each keyword it consider as feature. For around 12K features it is working fine. But I added one categories having 5 lacks keyword(seprated by newline char) then it gives this error :

```
  File "term_classify.py", line 51, in <module>
    classifier = obj.run_classifier(cltype)
  File "/root/Desktop/karim/software/nlp/nltk/publish/lists/classifier_function.py", line 144, in run_classifier
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py", line 210, in train
    count = feature_freqdist[label, fname].N()
MemoryError
```

I checked few threads but no help. Did anyone ever face similar issue?

I am calling function in this way :

```
if(cltype == 'nb'):
    print 'classifier : ',cltype
    classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
```

`train_set` contains list of keywords (feature_value) for training purpose

Comment: Try using generators to yield items only when requested .

Comment: @Alexander: thanks for suggestion. suppose 5 lacks item, passing each individually; will it be advisable?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy, it saves a lot memory than using lists:

```
import numpy as np:
train_set=np.array(train_set)
```